# Test method issue for PageReference method

Tags: apex, code-coverage, pagereference

I am trying to to write a test method for my custom apex controller which contains a constructor and multiple PageReference methods, all returning null. I am trying something like this:

```
@isTest
Public class matchingcontacts_test
{
    static testMethod void testmatchingcontactController()
    {
        test.startTest();
        matching_contacts mc = new matching_contacts();
        
        PageReference pagerefacc = mc.get_account();
        System.assertEquals(pagerefacc,null);
        
        
        
        PageReference pagerefcreatecontact = mc.createcontact();
        System.assertEquals(pagerefcreatecontact,null);

        PageReference pagerefcreate_logs = mc.create_logs();
        System.assertEquals(pagerefcreate_logs,null);

        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Running this test always fails and I get an error "Argument cannot be null".

Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Well, you could at first take a look at the stack trace of an error, and then see at which line does an error occur. After that you could see what is a null at this line, and change it so it is not a null. Then test will work

Comment: your asserts are backwards -- the first argument is the expected value; the second argument is the actual value